# GeoServer on a subpath behind NGINX proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, gis, nginx-reverse-proxy, geoserver

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server with NGINX, Wordpress and GeoServer (deployed on Tomcat) installed.
I would like to have the Wordpress site available on the URL root `foo.bar.com/` and have the GeoServer available on a subpath `foo.bar.com/geoserver`. The Wordpress site is working and shows up on `foo.bar.com/`, but the GeoServer isn't working correctly on `foo.bar.com/geoserver`, see screenshot below.

[image: geoserver screenshot]

I have the following NGINX configuration:

```
server {
  server_name foo.bar.com;
  root /var/www/site;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location /geoserver/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
  location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
  location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
  location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }


  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate ***; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key ***; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  if ($host = foo.bar.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80;
  server_name foo.bar.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I did set the proxy base URL in the GeoServer global settings and did configure CSRF protection conform [this document](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/webadmin/csrf.html).

Am i still missing some configuration in NGINX?

Comment: After disabling 
`location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }`
GeoServer is more or less working, except for the login. And I would like to disable this only for GeoServer and not for everything.